# How can I suppress this superflous debugger output in Eclipse/EPIC?

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, output, epic

I have a strange problem with the Perl Debugger in EPIC. When I started using it, all worked fine as expected. I would set breakpoints, run a program in debug mode, step through it ... Then, something must have changed but I have no idea what. Now, the debugger or EPIC or Eclipse, I don't know who, sends tons of output to the console window that have nothing to do with my program but with the - seemingly to me - internals of EPIC or the Perl debugger. Here's a little cutout from this output, there is an endless amount of this and the things my program wants to output just get lost.

What is the problem here? I did not find any setting I could change in the preferences, I don't know what to search for, I couldn't find anything in the EPIC docs.

Edit: one thing I remember is I used "use diagnostics;" in another program that belongs to the project, but that is not run or used by the program that is producing this debug output. Maybe it has something to do with that? Can it "get stuck" and be remembered by the debugger later? I know it sounds silly, but that's all I got.

```
  DB<396> ;{    
do 'dumpvar_epic.pm' unless defined &dumpvar_epic::dump_lexical_vars;

my $offset = 0;
my $savout = CORE::select($DB::OUT);
dumpvar_epic::dump_lexical_vars($offset);
CORE::select($savout);
};

12|$forceingest|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x40fb5a4)|3|'0'|1|3
4|$lll|1|2|14|REF(0x2739ff4)|37|Log::Log4perl::Logger=HASH(0x41bbe64)|3|...|1|3
9|$reingest|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x40fbf14)|3|'1'|1|3
13|$secondsPause|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x40fb774)|5|'300'|1|5
4|$tdh|1|2|14|REF(0x40ff0dc)|15|GLOB(0x42e7484)|3|...|1|3
12|$transferDir|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x40f9f24)|31|'c:/temp/xml/transfer/probleme'|2|31
8|$usedata|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x40fbf84)|3|'1'|1|3
6|%datah|1|1|15|HASH(0x40f2f8c)|3|...|1|3
5|@data|1|1|16|ARRAY(0x41002ec)|3|...|1|3
13|@transactions|1|1|16|ARRAY(0x40ff07c)|3|...|1|3
14|@transferFiles|1|1|16|ARRAY(0x40ff04c)|3|...|1|3
7|@tx_ref|1|1|16|ARRAY(0x40feffc)|3|...|1|3

  DB<397> ;{    
do 'dumpvar_epic.pm' unless defined &dumpvar_epic::dump_lexical_vars;

my $offset = 0;
my $varexpr = <<'EOT';
${$h->{'$lll'}}
EOT
my $subref = \&dumpvar_epic::dump_hash_expr;
my $savout = CORE::select($DB::OUT);
my $savbuf = $|;
$| = 0;
$subref->($offset, $varexpr);
$| = $savbuf;
print "";
CORE::select($savout);
};

3|ALL|1|2|14|REF(0x41d9f64)|15|CODE(0x41dbee4)|3|...|1|3
5|DEBUG|1|2|14|REF(0x41d9ba4)|15|CODE(0x41dbee4)|3|...|1|3
5|ERROR|1|2|14|REF(0x41d737c)|15|CODE(0x41d9b34)|3|...|1|3
5|FATAL|1|2|14|REF(0x41d735c)|15|CODE(0x41d9b34)|3|...|1|3
4|INFO|1|2|14|REF(0x41d748c)|15|CODE(0x41d9b34)|3|...|1|3
3|OFF|1|2|14|REF(0x41d9fe4)|15|CODE(0x41d9b34)|3|...|1|3
5|TRACE|1|2|14|REF(0x41d9ee4)|15|CODE(0x41dbee4)|3|...|1|3
4|WARN|1|2|14|REF(0x41d717c)|15|CODE(0x41d9b34)|3|...|1|3
10|additivity|1|1|17|SCALAR(0x41d52bc)|3|'1'|1|3
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention what is connected to your code, and what is not. It seems to be running (with `do`) a file called `dumpvar_epic.pm`, is that your file? If not, what is in it?

Comment: Nope, not mine. I have no idea what that is... seems to be part of EPIC itself.

Comment: When I google that module I get one relevant thread at http://www.epic-ide.org/tracker/debugger-throwing-errors.php. The discussion seems related to the same issue, but doesn't help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. There is indeed a setting for that under Preferences/Perl EPIC/Enable Debugger Console. I enabled that setting previously because of another weird problem with the debugger (threads wouldn't terminate any more and hang there until Eclipse was restarted), which seemed to work. Disabling it stops the unwanted output. Maybe there's something really weird going on with Perl/EPIC on my computer...